# Cannot wake up from suspend on ryzen 7 3700u

Tags: suspend

I installed Ubuntu on my HP Envy 360, but I couldn't wake up from suspend.
I installed `mesa-utils`, `xscreensaver` and `gnome-screensaver` to solve this problem, but it doesn't work.

So, does anyone know how to fix this problem?

## Postscript

> Could you please elaborate as to what exactly fails while trying to wake from suspend? How are you attempting wake, what errors (if any) are shown, and how far does the computer boot (again - if at all)?

If i tried to wake up from suspend, the computer's power is still on and the screen is blank. And I cannot know what error happend because the screen is blank. Then I can use the computer with force reboot.
I've never seen that the suspend worked.

> Have you updated your BIOS/firmware to the latest HP offers and which kernel are you running?

I updated to latest BIOS F.19 yesterday but doesn't work on both kernel 5.3 and kernel 5.4. (ubuntu 19.10 and ubuntu 20.04)

## Postscript

I noticed that the broblem is in desktop session because the suspend is worked on CUI (Ctrl+Alt+f4). But if it worked on CUI , I cloudn't login to GUI session.

```
$ sudo pm-suspend
[ 301.566028] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x387200040 flags=0x0070]
[ 301.566037] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: AND-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0000 address=0x387200040 flags=0x0070]
[ 302.588486] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: [drm:amdgpu_ib_ring_tests [amdgpu]] *ERROR* IB test failed on gfx (-110). 
[ 302.588572] [drm:amdgpu_device_delayed_init_work_handler [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ib ring test failed (-110).

## I pressed some keys, then the CUI session came back
$ reboot
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate as to what *exactly* fails while trying to wake from suspend? How are you attempting wake, what errors (if any) are shown, and how far does the computer boot (again - if at all)?

Comment: Have you updated your BIOS/firmware to the latest HP offers and which kernel are you running?  Add requested information by editing your question rather than in a comment.

Comment: Same issue here. This has to do with the Vega Radeon driver. I have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Om HHP-15-efo875ms also with ryzen7 3700u and vega 10 graphhics i had issuies running 19 and 20 as well and amd currently running ubuntu 18.04 after install i ran in terminal ...

```
sudo apt updatte && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

then

```
sudo apt install git-y
```

then

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

.
the last command will upgrade the kernal .. I also max my screensaver timeouts and sleep never if charge cable attached ..

Comment: the kernal uipgrade will help with all 3700u and vega10 graphics and helps get wifi drivers working .

Comment: Is the kernel 5.5? Now i switched Manjaro KDE cause its package manager. And I know it didn't work on kernel 5.5 even on ubuntu 20.04.